# SQL Error log maintenance

Tags: sql-server, maintenance

I have a few questions about the SQL Server error logs.

1. Are there any performance gains for recycling the SQL Error log?
2. How often should you recycle it?

Comment: (1) Performance gain can be seen if you are using monitoring software that scans the error log. The smaller the error log the quicker it will scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any performance gains for recycling the SQL Error log?

Not in terms of sql server's performance. Better for maintenance and when you want to find specific error - the size of the log file will affect any app or even opening the error log.

To recycle error log - use `EXEC sp_cycle_errorlog`. You can even schedule this using a sql agent job on a weekly or biweekly (depending on the activity of your server).

If you have Logshipping, to avoid getting your log bloat, I use `TF 3226`

> How often should you recycle it?

It depends ! I have it every week on my prod servers with a maximum of 10 error logs (`Limit the number of error log files before they are recycled` setting in sql server log --> configure option) .

This is official from Microsoft - [How to manage the SQL Server error log ?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2199578)

Comment: I keep as many error logs as I have transaction log backups, which usually equates to 30 days. It's very easy to cycle through 10 logs if there's a problem starting up SQL Server. 30 might be overkill, but it's not 99 (which is the limit).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no performance gains in recycling itself, but there can be a DBA productivity gain, such as in trouble-shooting time, when you need to find out some event messages in the log.

As for how often you need to recycle it, it really depends, but I suggest you can do it based on log size, and you can refer this for the details
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3229/cycle-sql-server-error-logs-based-on-size-using-powershell/